# is it possible to create a windows service which pop up a windows application

Tags: c#

is it possible to create a windows service which pop up a windows application and we can save values into a list through that application. Want to create a windows service for running every two hours and save values to a share point list.

Comment: Why do you need to popup another process, can't you just do all the processing in the service

Comment: yes it is however you need to run it under a user account that has the correct permissions as well as checking the box in the service settings to interact with desktop. Windows Service however is NOT the right way to go about doing this.

Comment: Much easier would be to use the windows task scheduler like [here](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/unbenanntzc94j15oyl.png) and [here](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/unbenannt2wvxqylkuf9.png).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but I don't think you should. For typical user interactions you could also create a startup application which will be easier to manage and interact with a user, or use the Task Scheduler.

To answer your question, Windows services can be user interactive, which means they can have access to the user's user interface (aka desktop). You can use that to show messages to users and ask for input. Read more on how to enable this and how the internals work on MSDN: [Interactive Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

From MSDN:

> use the [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) function to run the application within the context of the interactive user

So you can start an external application to interact with the user, save some information in some list or database, and move on.

Comment: @Vis: need more help? Was this post useful to you?